# /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Tags: python3, pip

I am following this tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install and more specifically:
**Install the Object Detection API**

When I run this command:

```
python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

I tried the following combinations:

```
UbuntuUser@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TensorFlow/models/research$ sudo python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
UbuntuUser@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TensorFlow/models/research$ sudo python3 -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .

Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --use-feature
UbuntuUser@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TensorFlow/models/research$ sudo python3 -m pip3 install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3
UbuntuUser@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TensorFlow/models/research$ sudo python -m pip3 install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip3
```

Both **pip** and **pip3** are install in Ubuntu Mate:

What is wrong?? I tried on google: [/usr/bin/python: No module named pip , after installing pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350119/usr-bin-python-no-module-named-pip-after-installing-pip) it didn't help...

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and retry.

Comment: You can see pip does work for `python3 -m pip`, you might have to update it. What does it print out when you do `python3 -m pip -V`? It's saying the `--use-feature` option doesn't exist, you might have to update it

Comment: @N0rbert: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 194 not upgraded.`

Comment: @GammaGames: `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: @GammaGames: How do I update it?

Comment: I tried this command: `pip install --upgrade pip` it successfully updated it but nothing was changed...

Comment: @just_learning That option was added in 20.0.3, the `pyhon3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` should have worked. What if you leave off the option?

Comment: @GammaGames: You mean not to run that command? Will the rest of the tutorial work?

Comment: @just_learning I mean to only run `python -m pip install .` and see what happens. The `--use-feature=2020-resolver` is a feature added to allow users to use a newer dependency resolver.

Comment: Ok, I followed with your command. When I go to training part, I get this: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7107, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: jpeg::Uncompress failed. Invalid JPEG data or crop window.
  [[{{function_node case_cond_cond_jpeg_true_216}}{{node case/cond/cond_jpeg/DecodeJpeg}}]]
  [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
  [[RemoteCall]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]`  What is wrong?

Comment: This suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586443/tensorflow-error-when-trying-transfer-learning-invalid-jpeg-data-or-crop-windo didn't help...

Comment: @just_learning I'm not sure, but that would be a problem for another question. I'm not familiar enough with tensorflow to know what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, pip does work when invoked with `python3 -m pip`. From the comments we've discovered that you are running v20.0.2. The `--use-feature` option was not added until 20.2 and, since the usual command to upgrade pip was not working, we omitted the option and it ran successfully.